# Add Objects to NSMutableArray in a Loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, nsmutablearray

I have problems getting NSMutableArray to work. I simplified the code for illustrating my problem. I have a class, which I use as a Data container.

```
@interface Question : NSObject {
int questionID;
NSString* text;
}

@property int questionID;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* text;

@end
```

I am creating different instances of this container as follows:

.h

```
#import "Question.h"

@interface testViewController : UIViewController {
NSMutableArray* questions;
}

-(IBAction) start;
```

.m

....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    questions=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      int questionID=i;
      Question* question=[[Question alloc]init];
      question.questionID=questionID;
      question.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text %d",i];
      [questions addObject:question];
      [question release];
    }   
}
```

..........

```
-(IBAction) start{
   for (int i=0; i<[questions count]; i++) {
       Question *theQuestion;
       theQuestion=(Question*)[questions objectAtIndex:i];
       NSLog(@"%d",theQuestion.questionID);
       NSLog(@"%@",theQuestion.text);
       NSLog(@"----------------------");
   }
}
```

In ViewDidLoad instances of question are created in a loop and they are added to the NSMutableArray questions. After question has been added it is released. After populating the NSMutableArray a function start is executed by pressing a button on the UI. This function should print out the contents of the different questions.

The  problem is when the function start is executed the NSMutableArray questions does not have the contents stored before and the program crashes on

```
NSLog(@"%d",theQuestion.questionID);
```

The interesting thing is that if I do not release the question on the function viewDidLoad, then everything works fine. However, I would miss releasing a variable I previously allocated and this should lead to a leak.

Does anybody has an idea how to do this properly?

Comment: Just after you add question to the array, but before you release it, try NSLog(@"retainCount %i",question.retainCount); to confirm it's 2, since at that point it should be.

Comment: I just tried printing the retainCount and at the first iteration it prints 2. As I go further on the loop it increases to 3,4,etc. This is strange as I allocate question in every iteration. According to my understanding it should stay at 2 over the whole loop isn't it?

Comment: On a sidenote, you should avoid doing this: i<[questions count] in the loop.  As the loop iterates, the method call happens each time which is wasteful. Better to use a temporary storage variable before the loop to store the count.

Comment: good point darren. I just wrote this very quickly to illustrate my problem. I will take it into account.

Comment: Have you overridden the isEqual of Question?

Comment: No NJones. Actually Question is quite simple as I wanted it to be the smallest piece of code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The incrementing retainCount does seem quite odd. Try adding 
    NSLog(@"%@",questions); to the end of the viewDidLoad function. If you have not overridden description it should give you a Hex value for each question, just confirm that all of them are not the same.

Comment: NJones, I just tried to print out the address of questions with NSLog(@"%@",questions) before and after releasing the question [question release]. The behavior is very strange as the program crashes on the printing after the release of question. This has no explanation for me as I would have expected that [questions addObject:question] should have done a retain on question. For some reason I do not know this is not true for this code and I cannot see why as this behavior contradicts the rules of memory management in OBjectiveC

Comment: I was checking the addresses I get for question in the loop and it looks really weird. After the release of question the array just get damaged and I have no explanation for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that your issue lies elsewhere in your code, memory issues expose themselves in strange ways. Are you sure nothing else interacts with `questions` and its contents? I suggest you add a breakpoint to the code and explore its contents at the point of the crash.

Comment: It is very weird that when I inspect the content of questions just before the crash then I do not see anything useful in the array. But if I just delete the retain line then the content is ok but I do not feel comfortable leaving something unreleased.

Comment: I suggest you have the LLVM static analyser tell you what you're doing wrong - I suspect the issue is elsewhere in your code. Invoke it from Product > Analyse.

Comment: Thanks Benjie for the suggestion. I just run the static analyzer using build & analyze and I do not get any errors or hints from there. Actually, after working in a bigger project I just wrote this small program for illustrating my problem. There is no so much code actually. I am sure it is some subtle thing but I cannot see it yet

Answer (score -1):

When creating Question delete release and use this instead:

```
Question* question=[[[Question alloc]init] autorelease];
```

Also it might be a good idea to use autorelease pool here.

Comment: The memory treatment of question is fine - autorelease adds no benefit whatsoever at the cost of a (very small) performance penalty.

Comment: I tried it with autorelease and it also crashes. The only way I get this to work is if I delete the [question release] line. But then I do not like the solution from the memory management point of view